# Flutter Email sender without the default iOS mail app: default mail app not available

Tags: flutter, dart, email, email-attachments

I am using [flutter_mail_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender) to send mails with attachments. It is working quite fine but there is a bug:

On iOS, if I have any other Mail app than the default Apple Mail App I get this error:

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(UNAVAILABLE, default mail app not available, null, null)

Like I said, when having the default Apple Mail App on my phone, everything works as expected. But is there any way to send a mail with attachment with any other Mail App?

What am I missing here?